# "The day before yesterday"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I was wondering, what single word could I use to describe the day before yesterday? E.g.

> My birthday was the day before yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Though kind of silly (the word is considered obsolete), [*ereyesterday*](http://www.wordsense.eu/ereyesterday/) could work: